# Mongodb command 'show collections' shows nonexistent collections

Tags: mongodb, database

In mongo shell:

```
> show collections
25420768
37310514
38222868
39065677
40516351
40583840
40892914
41005003
42991119
```

Let's look at the `25420768` collection:

```
> db['25420768'].find({})
2015-08-28T16:15:23.568-0500 TypeError: Cannot call method 'find' of undefined
> db['25420768'].drop()
2015-08-28T16:16:58.577-0500 TypeError: Cannot call method 'drop' of undefined
```

How do I remove these phantom (and admittedly poorly named) collections from my database?

Comment: Maybe there are some hidden chars. What's the output of `db.getCollectionNames()` ?

Comment: as @JohnnyHK is mentioning try something like: 
colls = db.getCollectionNames()
db[collections[X]].drop()

Comment: `> db[db.getCollectionNames()[0]].drop()`
`2015-08-30T16:43:02.093-0500 TypeError: Cannot call method 'drop' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same error,

db['25420768'].drop() wouldn't work, but db.getCollection('25420768').drop() would.